# What arguments do I pass to the client when running the boost::asio sockets examples

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am learning how to use the boost asio libraries and I am using the UDP examples on visual studio 2008. I have compiled and run the server application(name **udp_server.exe**). I have tried to run the client application but is does connect to the server. How do I specify the host and service name to the application for it to connect. I have specified the machine name but I get an error *"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"*. Are there some prerequisite setup I need to perform on my Windows 7 machine to get the examples to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to the "[Daytime.4 - A synchronous UDP daytime client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime4.html)" example, the server's host name is passed as `argv[1]` (the first command-line parameter) to the [udp::resolver::query ctor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver_query/basic_resolver_query/overload3.html). As you can see from the docs, the port is passed as the 3rd parameter to the ctor. This parameter can be a string representation of the port number or a "service name". Quoting the docs about this:

> On POSIX systems, service names are
>   typically defined in the file
>   /etc/services. On Windows, service
>   names may be found in the file
>   c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\services.

If all this seems ok and connection still fails, check the firewall settings on the server to make sure that it allows connections on the chosen port.